# Deklination von "Dona Scripta"

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, loanword

Vereinzelt wird "Dona Scripta" als Bezeichnung für eine Festschrift (Sammlung von Beiträgen verschiedener Autoren zu Ehren eines Jubilars) verwendet.  Aber wie wird "Dona Scripta" grammatikalisch behandelt? Nach meinen verschütteten Lateinkenntnissen dürfte das der Plural sein von lat. *donum* - das Geschenk (stimmt das so? Ich müsste in "Asterix der Legionär" nachschlagen ...). Das spräche für ein Pluraletantum im Neutrum. Leider hat mein Duden keinen Eintrag zwischen *Donarit* und *Donator* und ich bin nur auf wenige Fundstellen gestoßen, die überhaupt einen Hinweis geben, und wenn, dann eher unklar wie

> Abends überreichte Max Mustermann dem Jubilar feierlich die Dona Scripta.

Das passt zwar zu Neutrum Plural, aber auch zu Femininum Singular, und ich habe  manchmal den Eindruck, dass viele dies auch eher als letzteres angesehen, entweder weil sie die Endung *-a* (fälschlich?) für weiblich halten, oder quasi in Analogie zum gleichbedeutenden "*die* Festschrift".

**Q:** Neutrum Plural oder Femininum Singular?

**Q2:** Falls ersteres, wie sollte man über mehrere reden? Ist "Dona-Scripta-Festschriften" zu doppelt-gemoppelt?

Comment: Das scheint mir ja wohl eine Frage über die lateinische Sprache zu sein. Dies hier ist aber eine Q&A-Seite über die deutsche Sprache.

Comment: donum, i, n. 1. Gabe, Geschenk 2. Opfer, Weihgeschenk. scriptum, i, n. 1. Linie 2. Geschriebenes, Aufsatz, Schrift. aus: "Der kleine Stowasser", München, 1971.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Dem möchte ich entgegensetzen, dass in bestimmten Anwendungsbereichen der deutschen Sprache (vor allem natürlich im akademischen Sozialraum) der korrekte Einsatz lateinischer Ausdrücke durchaus relevant ist. Insofern gehört die Frage also doch zur deutschen Sprache. Bedenke auch, dass im Kontext anderer Sprachen (wie etwa im Englischen oder Amerikanischen) der Umgang mit lateinischen Ausdrücken teilweise anders ist.

Comment: PS: Der gemeine Ami scheut ja nicht davor zurück, *a visa* zu beantragen, wo er eigentlich ein Visum bräuchte. Oft zählt er sich auch - und das ist jetzt kein Witz - zur Spezies *homo sapien* [sic!], weil er *homo sapiens* für eine Pluralform hält. Die Subspezies *homo sapiens ignorans* ist leider recht individuenreich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann _"Die Subspezies homo sapiens ignorans ist leider recht individuenreich. "_ Immerhin haben sie ja jetzt einen prominenten Anführer ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Ich fürchte, sie hat mehrere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Gilt Christian Geiselmann jetzt schon als prominent?

Comment: @userunknown Ist Christian ein _"Ami"_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ich habe "ignorans" nicht mit "transatlans" übersetzt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Neben Unsicherheit im Lat. geht es auch um den Umgang im Deutschen. Genus und Numerus immer 1:1 übernehmen? Als Ergänzung: Was wäre, wenn die Ursprungssprache ganz andere Genera und/oder Numeri hätte als das Deutsche?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Möglicherweise relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfEqAolZFB0

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Oh, PS: Auch du verwendest lateinische Deklinationen in deutschen Sätzen: Du feierst Jesu (!) Geburt, machst an Christi (!) Himmelfahrt einen Ausflug und verleugnest möglicherweise Mariä (!) Empfängnis. Am Ende spielst du sogar ab und zu den *advocatus diaboli*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  "Extinction of homo sapien": Ja.., ich weiß nicht, wie es um *homo sapien* steht, aber *homo sapiens* ist auf jeden Fall auf dem absteigenden Ast...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Ad quaestionem primam:***

Gepflegte Ausdrucksweise im Deutschen wird hier unbedingt die Gegebenheiten des Lateinischen würdigen und also beim Neutrum Plural bleiben:

> Hiermit überreichen wir Ihnen ehrerbietigst unsere Dona scripta. Und zu den (!) Dona scripta hier noch eine Flasche Wein. Prosit!

Man kann noch über die Schreibweise diskutieren. Vielleicht möchte man es klein schreiben und kursiv setzen:

> Zu den *dona scripta* und dem Wein hier noch eine Dose Kekse.

Ich persönlich finde diese Variante die beste. Aber vielleicht bin ich hier etwas altmodisch oder pingelig.

Wenn man natürlich die Latinizität sehr ernst nimmt, könnte man auch dazu tendieren, die lateinische Deklination auch im deutschen Satz beizubehalten, wie das, sagen wir, zur Barockzeit bei uns noch weithin üblich war:

> Zu den *donis scriptis* und dem Wein hier noch eine Dose Kekse. - Nach dieser langen *laudatione* aber: *nunc est bibendum!*

Die Frage ist wohl, welches Publikum man hat: ob es nämlich mit lateinischen Deklinationen per Du ist. Ist es das aber, wird man sich ob dieser deklinartorischen Sorgfalt breiten Applauses sicher sein können.

***Ad quaestionem secundam:***

Eine *dona-scripta*-Festschrift wäre so doppeltgemoppelt wie ein *equus*-Pferd oder ein *canis*-Hund. Davon sollte man besser *abstare*-abstandnehmen. *Dona scripta* sind einfach *complures*-mehrere und darum Plural. Dass sie meisten in einem Buch zusammengebunden sind, ist in dieser Betrachtungsweise ein nachgeordneter Umstand. Möchte man nun aber über mehrere solcher Bände sprechen, könnte man sagen:

> Professor Schlauberger hat zum 70. Geburtstag gleich zwei verschiedene Sammlungen von *dona scripta* erhalten.
>
> In der Ehrenbibliothek des Hauses haben wir 700 Bände *dona scripta* [oder: *dona-scripta*-Bände] archiviert, die die akademischen Mitarbeiter dieser Institution im Laufe der letzten 150 Jahre zugeeignet bekommen haben.

Einfacher wäre es natürlich, man sagte *Festschriften*.

Sollte Professor Schlauberger nun zum 70. peinlicherweise nur einen einzigen Aufsatz gewidmet bekommen, weil sein Fachgebiet solitär und seine akademische Gefolgschaft gering ist und sich also keiner fand, einen weiteren halbwegs präsentablen Beitrag zu liefern, so könnte (ja, sollte) man schreiben oder sagen:

> Lieber Professor Schlauberger, ich freue mich, Ihnen hiermit mein *donum scriptum* überreichen zu dürfen. Lesen Sie es mit Bedacht, es ist einzig in seiner Art.

Comment: Wieso schreibst Du das Dona in Dona Scripta groß, das Scripta aber klein? Da es verstärkt unter Lateinischkönnern benutzt wird halte ich eine Pluralbildung wie im Latein für wahrscheinlich - ansonsten wäre profane Pluralbildung noch eine Option: "Ich hab die Dona Scriptas in die Tonne getreten". Ich kann aber nur 3-4 Phrasen Asterixlatein. "Sola Scriptura" habe ich aber schon mal gehört. :)

Comment: @userunknown  Ich stimme Dir zu, dass es etwas inkonsequent oder erratisch wirken kann, Dona großzuschreiben und scripta klein. Darum favorisiere ich auch *dona scripta*. Aber wenn schon mit Großschreibung, dann finde ich es immer noch besser, nur *dona* großzuschreiben (*Geschenke*, ein Substantiv), und *scripta* (*geschriebene*, ein Partizip Perfekt Passiv) klein, wie man das auch im Deutschen täte. Man schreibt ja auch nicht: *Um 17 Uhr beginnt die Anberaumte Weihnachtsfeier* sondern *Um 17 Uhr beginnt die anberaumte Weihnachtsfeier*.

Comment: Siehe auch § 55 Abs. 3 des amtlichen Regelwerks, https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6193#: "Die Großschreibung gilt auch (...) für Substantive aus anderen Sprachen, wenn sie nicht als Zitatwörter gemeint sind. Sind sie mehrteilig, wird der erste Teil großgeschrieben. Beispiele:
_(...) die Conditio sine qua non, das Cordon bleu, eine Terra incognita (...)_"

Comment: @johnl  - Danke. Mir war gar nicht bewusst, dass mein Bauch- bzw. Stilgefühl sogar normativ unterfütterbar ist.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese gleichzeitig fundierte wie humorvolle Antwort auf meine Fragen. Zum Zusatzpunkt, im Deutschen die Deklination aus dem Lateinischen beizubehalten, möchte ich allerdings ergänzen, dass ich so etwas schon immer für Unsinn gehalten habe, weil das Verfahren nicht übertragbar ist (wie würde man umgekehrt ein in einen lateinischen Satz eingebautes deutsches Wort mit der deutschen Deklination übernehmen, wenn im Lateinischen der Ablativ erforderlich ist?)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Was die Behandlung von deutschen Wörtern in lateinischen Sätzen angeht - das mögen die Römer entscheiden. *Cultura est* überall *diversa.*